# Jackson: understand if source JSON is an array or an object

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

Parsing JSON in Jackson library would require:

- for an object

  ```
  MapType hashMapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, Object.class);
  Map<String, Object> receivedMessageObject =  objectMapper.readValue(messageBody, hashMapType);
  ```
- for an array  of objects

  ```
  Map[] receivedMessage = objectMapper.readValue(messageBody, HashMap[].class)
  ```

What would be the best way to check whether I have array or object in messageBody, in order to route to the correct parsing? Is it just to directly check for array token in MessageBody?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An option is just to treat everything that might be an array as an array. This is often most convenient if your source JSON has just been auto-transformed from XML or has been created using an XML-first library like Jettison.

It's a sufficiently common use case that there's a Jackson switch for this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

You can then just deserialize a property into a collection type, regardless of whether it's an array or an object in the source JSON.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to know whether your input is an array or an object, you can simply use the `readTree` method. A simple example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String json1 = "{\"key\": \"value\"}";
String json2 = "[\"key1\", \"key2\"]";

JsonNode tree1 = mapper.readTree(json1);
System.out.println(tree1.isArray());
System.out.println(tree1.isObject());

JsonNode tree2 = mapper.readTree(json2);
System.out.println(tree2.isArray());
System.out.println(tree2.isObject());
```

If you want to be able to deserialize to multiple types, have a look at [Polymorphic Deserialization](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did based on the answer from @ryanp :

```
public class JsonDataHandler {
    public List<MyBeanClass> createJsonObjectList(String jsonString) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        List<MyBeanClass> jsonObjectList = objMapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<MyBeanClass>>(){});
        return jsonObjectList;
    }
}
```